# Undefined behavior when working with the input stream

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

Why is this code contains undefined behavior (the program is completed in half the time). How do I make a clean shutdown of the reader when I need to complete the program?

```
public class Main implements Runnable {
    private static BufferedReader reader;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        new Thread(new Main()).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //System.in.close(); // <-- undefined behavior
            reader.close(); // <-- undefined behavior
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's undefined behavior? What does the run time of the code have anything to do with it? Please be more specific.

Comment: You can't start the main thread yourself. You can however, start other thread in main thread

Comment: Always close your resources in the `finally` block. It is always executed  whether the exception is raised or not.

Comment: I run this program in intellij idea. The process stops when all its threads are completed. This code will stop after time. Sometimes the program simply does not end.

Comment: @Vladislav Why did you write that program? What's the point?

Comment: Do you have to use a `BufferedReader` or can you use something else?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I tried to use the Scanner but with him I get the same problem.